# Number of rearrangements of the word "INDIVISIBILITY"

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can the word "**INDIVISIBILITY**" be rearranged, such
that no two **I**s come close to each other?

**My attempt**

Total number of ways of rearranging the word = $\dfrac{14!}{6!}$

Number of ways of rearranging the word such that at the least, a pair of **I**s come close to each other (the motivation for this comes from the negation of "no two **I**s come close to each other") = $\binom{6}{2} \times \dfrac{13!}{4!}$

Then, required number of arrangements = $\dfrac{14!}{6!} - \binom{6}{2} \times \dfrac{13!}{4!}$.

But this gives me a negative number. Where am I going wrong? Could anyone tell me how to go about this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are $8$ distinct letters, together with $6$ I's.

The $8$ non-I's can be arranged in $8!$ ways. Every such arrangement produces $9$ 'gaps" (the $7$ gaps between letters, and the $2$ 'endgaps") for us to slip a single I into. The $6$ gaps needed can be chosen in $\binom{9}{6}$ ways, for a total of $8!\binom{9}{6}$.

**Remark:** The $\binom{6}{2}\frac{13!}{4!}$ overcounts the cases where two *or more* I's are next to each other.

Comment: Oh, I see it now! Thank you for this remarkably simple solution. :)

Comment: You are welcome. The "gap" idea can be useful for problems in which we want no two consecutive objects of a certain type.

Answer (score 1):

You're counting some cases several times. For example, you're counting **IIIINDVSBILITY** both by putting the first **II** together and arranging the others, and putting the second **II** together and arranging the others.

What you need is to separate all the cases which is:

- All the **I**s are next to each other.
- Only 5 **I**s are next to each other.
- Only 4 **I**s are next to each other.
- 4 **I**s are next to each other and the two others are next to each other but apart from the first 4 **I**s
- etc